# LDAP authentication not working with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ldap

Please, help me out on below query :

I am trying to configure LDAP authentication in my Jenkins tool. I have done below setup on Jenkins for LDAP authentication,still I am not able to login.

**Server** : ldaps://rootdc1.myweb.com:636

**root DN** : DC=MYWEB,DC=COM

**User search base** : DC=MYWEB,DC=COM

**User search filter** : sAMAccountName={0}

**Group search base** : DC=MYWEB,DC=COM

**Manager DN** : CN=rhunt,OU=ApplicationUsers,DC=MYWEB,DC=COM

Below is the error coming when trying to login :

**Invalid login information. Please try again. 
Try again
If you are a system administrator and suspect this to be a configuration problem, see the server console output for more details.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you taken a look at the server console output ? Does it give more details about the login problem ?

Comment: Yes, it is giving information about login authentication in console output. Below is the error code :

Comment: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-0310020A, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT

Comment: The error message indicates that there is no such DN  as "CN=rhunt,OU=ApplicationUsers,DC=MYWEB,DC=COM" in you LDAP directory. Can you expand the DIT and check if the the hierarchy and the attributes of CN=rhunt are  correct ? You can use an LDAP browser like Apache Directory Studio to connect.

Comment: In Jenkins Configure Global Security, we need to pass only following parameters to successfully connect and login through LDAP authentication:
Server: ldaps://rootdc1.myweb.com:636       
Root DN: DC= DC=MYWEB,DC=COM        
User search filter: sAMAccountName={0}       
Manager DN: CN=rhunt,OU=ApplicationUsers,DC=MYWEB,DC=COM       
Manager Password: ********

Comment: Have you checked if the DN CN=rhunt,OU=ApplicationUsers,DC=MYWEB,DC=COM exists in your LDAP (Active Directory?) ?

Comment: Yes, it exists in AD and I am able to login, now, through LDAP authentication with the settings i mentioned earlier. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That is good. You might want to close this question by updating the answer section below with the root cause of the problem and solution so that it helps some one else with a similar problem.

Answer (score 3):

In Jenkins Configure Global Security, we need to pass parameters only to following tabs to successfully connect through LDAP authentication and leave remaining fields empty:

Server: ldaps://rootdc1.myweb.com:636

Root DN: DC= DC=MYWEB,DC=COM

User search filter: sAMAccountName={0}

Manager DN: CN=rhunt,OU=ApplicationUsers,DC=MYWEB,DC=COM

Manager Password: ********

Comment: This helped! I switched User search filter from uid to sAMAccountName={0} and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins [LDAP Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ldap-plugin/blob/241b4c2495f83498124e2998104df0147913a4de/src/main/java/jenkins/security/plugins/ldap/LDAPConfiguration.java#L534), there is a method `normalizeUserSearchBase`

return  `userSearchBase + "," + rootDN;` which concat userSearchBase and rootDN.

So here you should fill the `User search base` field with value wiped off rootDN. in your case leave empty.